# How to use bibliographystyle for attach file?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

How to use bibliographystyle for attach file?

I use `apa-good.bst` style, but unfortunately the authors' names and year are not bold.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage
[style=ext-authoryear,labelnumber, useprefix=true,
sorting=nyt,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=3,uniquelist=false, backend=biber,
doi=true,isbn=true,url=true,
uniquename=false,bibencoding=utf8, date=year, giveninits=true, terseinits=false,
dashed=false, punctfont=true]
{biblatex}
\addbibresource{b.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{\mkbibbold{\mkbibparens{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
\cite{Achenbach75,AchenbachGM80,AdamV04}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The `b.bib` file:

```
@book{Achenbach75,
author = {Achenbach, J.},
title = {Wave Propagation in Elastic Solids},
edition = {First Edition},
publisher  = {Elsevier Science Publishing Compancy},
address = {Amsterdam},
year = 1975,
isbn = {9780720403251},
}

@article{AchenbachGM80,
author = {Achenbach, J. and Gautesen, A. K. and Mendelsohn, D. A.},
title = {Ray Analysis of Surface-Wave Interation with an Edge Crack},
journal = {IEEE Transactions on Sonics and Ultrasonics},
volume = {SU-27},
year = 1980,
number = 3,
pages = {124-129},
}

@article{AdamV04,
author = {Adam, M. and von~Estorff, O.},
title = {Reduction of Train-Induced Building Vibrations by Using Open and Filled Trenches},
journal = {Computers and Structures},
pages = {11-24},
year = 2004,
volume = 83,
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: @H.Gorbanzad, I know. Hope someone else helps improving my answer..

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: @H.Gorbanzad, I slightly improved my answer.

Comment: It is possible to send me your email. xepersian.print@gmail.com and Telegram ID: @Gonashnegar